# read numbers from a file specified on the command line and print the sum of the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that inputs a list of numbers from a file and prints their sum. The file name comes in as a command-line argument. Assuming the file "orange" contains the numbers:

```
6 26 10 8
```

Your program should behave as follows:

```
 python3 a4.py orange
 50
```

My current code:

```
from scanner import *
def main():
    s = Scanner("orange")
    print(sum(float(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))
    s.close()
main()
```

For my code to do that I will need to implement a scanner correct? However, when I run the updated code with the scanner, it returns a `cannot convert string to float: orange`. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but Im taking my first programming class and I'm trying to get ahead.

Comment: Show us your current code, else it would be difficult to help.

Comment: Looks like you've done little besides posting your assignment.

Comment: What do you mean by *"implement a scanner"*? Why would you try to convert the first argument, a string, into a float? Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code and the full error traceback.

Comment: Note that the error is due to a bad conversion. You try to do something like `float("orange")` what is obviously impossible!

Comment: not sure why I forgot to put in my code lol

Comment: @user3754670 did you get it to work by now?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a scanner, you can just get the filename from `sys.argv` and read the file like this:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    print(sum(float(x) for x in f.read().split()))
```

output for your sample file:

```
 >> python3 a4.py orange
 50.0
```

If it's guaranteed that there are only integers in your file you can use `int(x)`.

Comment: when I go to test that code it returns a syntax error and shows a blank line :/ sorry again, im new to this and im trying my best to learn :)

Comment: '$ python3 a4.py apple
  File "a4.py", line 4

                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3754670 the code has 3 lines, so I am really fascinated that you get an error in line 4.

Comment: ..that's what im saying! haha

Comment: @user3754670 it's almost certain you copy-pasted it wrong.

Comment: I literally checked for certain that it contained only 3 lines, I had a blank line syntax error return lik ethat